# Set price is select option equal to

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code for my project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Merc</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <select id="merc" name="merc[]" onchange="getPris()">
    <option hidden disabled selected value></option>
    <option value="apple12">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana33">Banana</option>
    <option value="pear1">Pear</option>
    <option value="fish5">Fish</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><p name="prislabel[]"></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <select id="merc" name="merc[]" onchange="getPris()">
    <option hidden disabled selected value></option>
    <option value="apple12">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana33">Banana</option>
    <option value="pear1">Pear</option>
    <option value="fish5">Fish</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><p name="prislabel[]"></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <select id="merc" name="merc[]" onchange="getPris()">
    <option hidden disabled selected value></option>
    <option value="apple12">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana33">Banana</option>
    <option value="pear1">Pear</option>
    <option value="fish5">Fish</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><p name="prislabel[]"></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <select id="merc" name="merc[]" onchange="getPris()">
    <option hidden disabled selected value></option>
    <option value="apple12">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana33">Banana</option>
    <option value="pear1">Pear</option>
    <option value="fish5">Fish</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><p name="prislabel[]"></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <select id="merc" name="merc[]" onchange="getPris()">
    <option hidden disabled selected value></option>
    <option value="apple12">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana33">Banana</option>
    <option value="pear1">Pear</option>
    <option value="fish5">Fish</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><p name="prislabel[]"></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <select id="merc" name="merc[]" onchange="getPris()">
    <option hidden disabled selected value></option>
    <option value="apple12">Apple</option>
    <option value="banana33">Banana</option>
    <option value="pear1">Pear</option>
    <option value="fish5">Fish</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><p name="prislabel[]"></p></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

<script>

function getPris() {
$(document.querySelectorAll('select[name="merc[]"]')).each(function(i,obj) {

if (document.getElementsByName("merc[]")[i].value == "apple12") {
        document.getElementById("prislabel").innerHTML = "499";
    }
        
});
}

</script>
```

What I am trying to do is the following:
If the user select for example Apple from the option, I want the `priceLabel` on the same row to be 499,-. If the next row after that row also is Apple, I want the `priceLabel` on the second row to be 249,-. So If there are two rows with the same option value, I want the 2nd row to have price 249,-., and third if the also Apple. If the user select Banana, I want price 699,- and the new row 249,- if its Banana.

I have tried something as your can see in the code, but the code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe the problem inside your code is the way you get an element and the looping.

I have refined your code below, and change some `class` and `id`:

Note: And also it's the best practice to put the CSS and JavaScript file in the different file. In this case, I put all the three files in the same folder.

**HTML (filename: `index.html`):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> <!-- THIS LINE IS TO CONNECT TO THE CSS FILE -->
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Goods</th>
                <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      <!-- FIRST ROW ========================== -->
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select class="goods" onchange="seePrice()">
                        <option hidden disabled selected value>>-- Select Item --<</option>
                        <option value="apple">Apple</option>
                        <option value="banana">Banana</option>
                        <option value="pear">Pear</option>
                        <option value="fish">Fish</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="prislabel">$0.0</p>
                </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- SECOND ROW ========================== -->
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select class="goods" onchange="seePrice()">
                        <option hidden disabled selected value>>-- Select Item --<</option>
                        <option value="apple">Apple</option>
                        <option value="banana">Banana</option>
                        <option value="pear">Pear</option>
                        <option value="fish">Fish</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="prislabel">$0.0</p>
                </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- THIRD ROW========================== -->
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select class="goods" onchange="seePrice()">
                        <option hidden disabled selected value>>-- Select Item --<</option>
                        <option value="apple">Apple</option>
                        <option value="banana">Banana</option>
                        <option value="pear">Pear</option>
                        <option value="fish">Fish</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="prislabel">$0.0</p>
                </td>
      </tr>
            <!-- YOU CAN ADD MORE ROW BELOW THIS LINE ========================== -->
    </table>
    <script src="function.js"></script> <!-- THIS LINE IS TO CONNECT TO THE JS FILE -->
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS (filename: `styles.css`):**

```
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

**JavaScript (filename: `function.js`):**

```
function seePrice() {
  const selectedItem = document.getElementsByClassName("goods");
  const priceTag = document.getElementsByClassName("prislabel");


  for (var i = 0; i < priceTag.length; i++){
    if (selectedItem[i].value == "apple") {
      priceTag[i].innerHTML = "$6.90";
    } else if (selectedItem[i].value == "banana"){
      priceTag[i].innerHTML = "$5.90";
    } else if (selectedItem[i].value == "pear"){
      priceTag[i].innerHTML = "$3.90";
    } else if (selectedItem[i].value == "fish"){
      priceTag[i].innerHTML = "$8.90";
    }
  }
}
```

You can see the live demo [here](https://codepen.io/hisamafahri/pen/yLaVdOo)